# How do you simulate and test the Application Update on Android and iphone

Tags: android, ios, testing, itunes, google-play

You have 1.1 version app already developed and is released in market & you are about to send update(release new version 1.2 )  in Play store/itunes  with some critical functional changes.

What are the ways do you follow to simulate situation like real time App Update that happen in Play store/itunes? How do you test that?

Common things which i cross checked before :

[Android](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en)

[Ios](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2285/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011323)

Sample Scenario :

I'm trying to trace down a database upgrade bug and need to figure out a 
way of simulating market upgrades.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can actually release into Play store as alpha and/or beta and test upgrade this way. It's best as it's a real upgrade from the store, nothing simulated.

You can read more here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

**EDIT**

You can also try something like that: have a copy of the code of the previous version. Upload it to a test device. Then upload the new code, this will force a database update which you will be able to debug.

Comment: I agree with the edit. I would be very surprised if the delivery method had anything to do with issues with the upgrade. Simply installing the previous version, and then installing the fixed version from your development environment or testing environment would be sufficient to cover 99.99% of upgrade bugs.

Comment: There needs to be a way to simulate an update locally rather than having to go through the Android Play Store Beta/Alpha steps.  It is unacceptable to have to wait 3+ hours for an app to be approved into the store in order to test any changes made.  Updating via APK does not seem to simulate the Play Store update process because bugs we are seeing in the Play Store updates can not be reproduced by manually updating via an APK.